# Make AnimationDrawable move Forward

Tags: java, android, drawable, android-animation

All- I have a simple app in which I want a man to walk across the screen. Right now the animation is happening in one place like a sticky note flip book. In other words the frames are changing in one place like a spinning wheel would. My question is **how can I get the animation to progress forward (at my desired pace) as well as change frames?** Here is my code concerning this issue:

```
public void start(View v) {  
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView); 
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation); 
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();                
    frameAnimation.start();
}
```

Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, using your own image(the image of the man):

Main Class:

```
package com.android.animation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity 
{

    Animation myView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myView = new Animation(this);
        setContentView(myView);
    }
}
```

Animation Class:

```
package com.android.animation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class Animation extends View
{
Bitmap gBall;
float changingY;

public Animation(Context content)
{
    super(content);

    gBall = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
    changingY = 0;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gBall, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY, null);
    if(changingY < canvas.getHeight())
        changingY += 10;
    else
        changingY = 0;

    invalidate();
}
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In fact, if you want you can go ahead and copy paste my code and see how it works(make sure to put an image in the drawable-hdpi folder)...  you should be able to use it as a template for your project.  Hope it helps!

P.S  You could of course, change the `ChangingY` variable to `ChangingX` (for example; of course you would have to change a couple other things like the `drawBitmap()` method..  not hard though) to make the ball move in a horizontal line...  see how it works out for you.

Comment: I am getting two errors on `myView = new Animation(this);
        setContentView(myView);` First on `Animation` as Eclipse is saying `Cannot instantiate the type Animation` and than on `setContentView` with `The method setContentView(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (Animation)` Any ideas?

Comment: That is really weird.. I have literally the exact same code as I posted, in eclipse, and it works perfectly.. :O  Make sure your Animation class EXTENDS View for the second error.  As for the first error...  Make sure you have the constructor in the Animation class set up correctly(the way i've posted up there).

Comment: That is strange. I copied your code into eclipse and still those two errors. Let me double check: `R.drawable.ball` is the list of images so mine would be `R.drawable.animation` right? Is there any libraries I have to add or anything in the manifest? Thanks for your support!

Comment: R.drawable.ball is linking to the ball.png file which is located in the drawable-hdpi folder.  If your image file is called animation.png, then yes, R.drawable.animation should work.  No, there shouldn't be anything to add in the manifest..   Make sure you've imported all the necessary packages(if you see an error in eclipse, in case you don't know this, you can hover over the words that are underlined with a red line and it will suggest to you the best way to fix the error.  If any of the suggestions say "Import..."  go ahead and click on the suggestion and it should import what's neccesary.)

Comment: Let me start a new project and copy your code exactly and see what happens.

Comment: Is your xml file called activity_main or just main?

Comment: My xml is called activity_main does that make a difference. (I changed `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);` to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` already.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15147/discussion-between-corecase-and-androidcurious)